# Не работают кнопки слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Хотел сделать, чтобы при нажатии на стрелки класс *-active* переходил к предыдущей, либо к следующей кнопке *slider__btn*. И при нажатии на не активную кнопку *slider__btn* она становилась активной. А текущая активная становилась наоборот неактивной.
Вроде все правильно написал, но почему то не работает.

```js
let sliderBtn = $('.slider__btn');

$('.slider__prev').click(function() {
  if (sliderBtn.hasClass('.-active')) {
    sliderBtn.removeClass('.active');
    sliderBtn.prev(sliderBtn).addClass('.-active');
  }
});

$('.slider__next').click(function() {
  if (sliderBtn.hasClass('.-active')) {
    sliderBtn.removeClass('.active');
    sliderBtn.next(sliderBtn).addClass('.-active');
  }
});

sliderBtn.click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('.-active')) {
    $(this).addClass('.-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.shop__slider {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 66px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev {
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  background: #95a5a6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 14px;
  font-family: FontAwesome, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev:hover::before {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 200ms, color 200ms;
  text-align: center;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn:hover .slider__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn .slider__link {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 66px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.shop__slider .-active {
  position: relative;
  background: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .-active .slider__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .-active::after {
  cursor: default;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 15px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  background: #95a5a6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 200ms;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 14px;
  font-family: FontAwesome, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next:hover::before {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="shop__slider">
  <div class="slider__prev">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__btn -active">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Хиты продаж</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__btn">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Акции</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__btn">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Новинки</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__next"></div>
</div>
```

---

#### Обновлено

Были выявлены синтаксические ошибки при написании класса у методов `hasClass`, `addClass`, `removeClass`.

Но остался вопрос. При нажатии на *prev/next* выбираются все кнопки. Как можно сделать, чтобы выбиралась только следующая или предыдущая кнопка?

Comment: Вы, прежде всего, несколько напутали с классами, должно быть `.hasClass('-active')`, то есть без точек. Ну и подобного рода ошибка: `.removeClass('.active')`

Comment: да, с этим уже разобрался. Но остался вопрос. При нажатии на prev/next выбираются все кнопки. Как можно сделать, чтобы выбиралась только следующая или предыдущая кнопка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  // Все вкладки c классом `.slider__btn`.
  var $tabs = $('.slider__btn');

  // Вешаем функцию обработчик на событие `click`.
  $tabs.on('click', function(event) {
    changeTab($(this).index('.slider__btn'));
  });

  $('.slider__prev').on('click', function(event) {
    let index = $tabs.filter('.-active').index('.slider__btn');

    changeTab(--index);
  });

  $('.slider__next').on('click', function(event) {
    let index = $tabs.filter('.-active').index('.slider__btn');

    changeTab(++index);
  });

  // Индекс вкладки на которую будем переключаться.
  // Отсчет индексов в `javascript` ведется от нуля.
  // Если индекс равен 0, значит это первая вкладка.
  // Если индекс равен 1, значит это вторая вкладка.
  // Переключим вкладку на вторую ч/з три секунды.
  var timerId = setTimeout(changeTab, 3000, 1);

  // Функция смены текущей вкладки.
  function changeTab(index) {
    // $tabs.length - количество вкладок.
    // a % b – это остаток от деления a на b.
    index = index % $tabs.length;

    // Меняем класс у текущей вкладки.
    $tabs.removeClass('-active').eq(index).addClass('-active');

    // Очищаем предыдущий таймер, чтобы
    // не было зацикливаний при постоянных кликах.
    clearTimeout(timerId);

    // Переключим вкладку на следующую ч/з три секунды.
    // ++ - увеличиваем активную вкладку на единицу.
    timerId = setTimeout(changeTab, 3000, ++index);
  }
});
```

```css
.shop__slider {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 66px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev {
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  background: #95a5a6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 14px;
  font-family: FontAwesome, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__prev:hover::before {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 200ms, color 200ms;
  text-align: center;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn:hover .slider__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__btn .slider__link {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 66px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.shop__slider .-active {
  position: relative;
  background: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .-active .slider__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .-active::after {
  cursor: default;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 15px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  background: #95a5a6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 200ms;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next::before {
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 14px;
  font-family: FontAwesome, serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.shop__slider .slider__next:hover::before {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop__slider">
  <div class="slider__prev"></div>
  <div class="slider__btn -active">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Хиты продаж</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__btn">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Акции</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__btn">
    <a href="#" class="slider__link">Новинки</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__next"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```